# Study the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigl( \sqrt[n]{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1\Bigr)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to study the convergence of

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl( \sqrt[n]{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1\biggr).
$$

Any help appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: this should be straightforward. What have you tried?

Comment: But for disappointing and, perhaps, also annoying the OP, I can't see how this is "straightforward". As both developed answers show, there's a non-trivial and non-immediate development to follow...

Comment: @Don: The straightforwardness is that, commonly, the very first thing you do to estimate a root like that is to write $$\sqrt[n]{1 + \frac{1}{n}} \approx 1 + \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$ and the sum converges with that estimate. The rest of the proof writes itself.

Comment: I beg to differ, and pretty strongly in fact, with you, @Hurkyl, and it's a fact that one of the answers doesn't resource to that. But it doesn't matter: the "commongly" done thing may well depend on how veteran the OP is in these battles and/or in what methods her/his instructor practiced the most.

Comment: @Hurkyl: That is an excellent point that at least can give (mostly unstated) motivation for comparison to $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ used in all of the answers.  I'd upvote that as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Now I've added to my answer making explicit an approach inspired by your comment.

Answer (score 18):

By the binomial theorem,
$$1\le 1+\frac 1n\le (1+\frac 1 {n^2})^n=1+n\frac 1 {n^2} +\binom{n}{2} (\frac 1 {n^2})^2+\dots,$$
so, taking $n$th roots,
$$1\le \sqrt[n]{1+\frac{1}{n}}\le 1 + \frac1 {n^2},$$
and the sum converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** We have 
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots +y^{n-1}).$$ 
Let $x=\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ and let $y=1$. Multiply top and (missing) bottom of your expression by $x^{n-1}+\cdots+y^{n-1}$, and look. The top is now nice and simple, and there is a big bottom.

Answer (score 4):

So you've only got clever algebraic arguments so far. Here is an average analytic approach for the sake of completeness.

I will use two ingredients.

1) By concavity of $\log$, we have $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for all $x>-1$.

2) By the mean value theorem, $e^x-1\leq ex$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Now
$$
0\leq \sqrt[n]{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}-1\leq e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}-1\leq \frac{e}{n^2}.
$$

So the series converges by comparison with the Riemann $p$-series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Show for $n$ sufficiently large,

$$\sqrt[n]{1 + \frac{1}{n}} < 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}$$

The convergence will follow from comparison test.

Comment: Greater than $1$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

So far we've seen an [average analytic argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/314553) to follow up on the clever algebraic arguments.  Here is a below average analytic argument.

Using l'Hôpital's rule,

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{1/n}-1}{\dfrac{1}{n^2}}
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^x-1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^x\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}+\log(1+x)\right)}{2x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^x\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{2(1+x)}+\frac{\log(1+x)}{2x}\right)\\
&=1.
\end{align*}$$

Convergence follows from the limit comparison test.

---

Alternatively, inspired by [Hurkyl's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314510/study-the-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-bigl-sqrtn1-frac1n-1-bi#comment681275_314510) about a common way to estimate roots near $1$ , let $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/n}$ with $n>1$ fixed.  Then $f(0)=1$, $f'(0)=\dfrac{1}{n}$, and $f''(x)< 0$ for all $x\geq 0$, and it follows that $f(x)< 1+\dfrac{x}{n}$ for all $x>0$.  In particular, $f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) <1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}$.

---

Here's a sketch of another way to answer this with the limit comparison test, without l'Hôpital.

Let $g(x)=(1+x)^x$.  Then $g$ is analytic in neighborhood of $x=0$, with $g(0)=1$ and $g'(0)=0$.  Hence $g(x)=1+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$, and $h(x)=\dfrac{g(x)-1}{x^2}=a_2+a_3x+\cdots$ is also analytic in a neighborhood of $x=0$, with $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}h(x)=a_2$.  Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/n}-1}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=a_2$, which implies that the series converges by limit comparison.

Comment: Below or not below, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach...

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), for $n\ge1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
1+\frac1n
&=1+\frac{n}{n^2}\\
&\le\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n
\end{align}
$$
Taking $n^{\text{th}}$ roots gives
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{1/n}\le1+\frac1{n^2}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{1/n}-1\right]
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}6
\end{align}
$$
That is, the series converges by comparison and the $p$-Test.